# Which machine learning method to use for geographic systems prediction?

Tags: svm, predictive-models, poisson-distribution, panel-data, libsvm

I am trying to do experiments on geographic systems prediction. We're working on classifying the location where we sell product most. So, we need to analyze the hestorical data and predict the success of our product in specific areas, specific time.

I don't have a lot of experience in statistics and modeling data beyond a high school statistics course so I'm kinda confused.

```
lat             long          city_block ..   event      date
41.98302392, -87.71849159,      23             1        17/04/2014  
41.77351707, -87.59144826,      44             0       17/04/2014  
41.77508317, -87.58899995,      24             0        17/04/2014  
41.77511247, -87.58646695,      33             1        17/04/2014  
41.77514645, -87.58515301,      21             0        17/04/2014  
41.77538531, -87.58611272,      22             3        17/04/2014  
41.71339537, -87.56963306,      39             0        16/04/2014 
41.81685612, -87.59757281,      12             0        16/04/2014  
41.81697313, -87.59910809,      02             3        16/04/2014 
41.81695808, -87.60049861,      3              0        16/04/2014 
41.75894604, -87.55560586,       4             0        16/04/2014
```

Event: represent number of items sold in location (lat/long) on (date).

Can anyone give an example how to classify geographic systems, and predict values based on data we have. as far as I know, I can't use linear modeling (as I have two variables lat/long).

Someone recommended to use density estimation Instead of using clustering. Using one-class SVM, is given points only from one class, and expected to learn a separation between members of that class and anything else. I read in another post that I have to use poisson, as it's counting model. Meanwhile, as I have a lot of negative points (90%), I will have problems finding good results.

What do you suggest as an approach to tackle this problem ?

Comment: One thing is that 'longitudinal' will mean something different round here than lat/long. ('longitudinal' meaning a separate time series for each store). Suggest you refine the question you're looking to answer (as without more data it looks as though a simple approach like counting up sales at stores would be best you do).

Comment: You are right! I edited the question. Just check if it makes sense now.

Answer (score 3):

Well, there are a lot of ways to treat this and the best answer may depend on what you're going to do with it (which is true with many questions on this board.)

One of the most flexible ways though would be to use a thin-plate spline with the response as either a Poisson or a Bernoulli (i.e. a logistic regression spline). There are a number of packages that will implement those, but one of the best is the `gss` package in R. (The documentation for that package should have some good examples, but the `gssanova` command is the one you're looking for.)

The benefit of a thin-plate spline is that it will allow the "surface" representing propensity to purchase as a function of geography to be very flexible in its shape (compared with a linear model, where it would be a plane). The primary downsides are a) if you have a lot of data, you will want to limit the number of knots to something reasonable for computation (which the package can do), and b) it's non-parametric, so any hypothesis testing you'd like to do will have some extra steps involved and if you need to explain this to a business person, you'll want to rehearse your wording.

Splines like this sometimes go by different names, like Kriging or spatial interpolation. It's the same idea though. If you're not familiar with splines, they're akin to a weighted-nearest-neighbors method where the weights decrease with distance (inverse-linearly, IIRC, though I'd have to check). Generally though, this method is most ideal if your location information is somewhat continuously distributed throughout the geography you're looking at, and where you expect that the propensity for sales at nearby geographies to be similar, (like a website that sold something weather related and the where geography points were addresses, for example). If you were, say, a department store, with few locations relative to the geography covered, this might work but it's likely that clustering the stores and examining each cluster separately would work better. But that's another way you could handle it, just cluster geographic points in a large enough grid and examine the grid one piece at a time.

Beyond that, if you have specific goals you're trying to accomplish there may be other ways that are preferable. Splines are very flexible though, they're just a little involved. If you have any specific questions about how to implement them, let me know and I can try to comment further.

Comment: What about calculating the next event using counting model (like: poisson), then use gaussian to calculate probability that this event would happen or no. Is this a good approach to tackle the prob ?

Comment: I'm not really sure what you mean by any of that. "Calculating the next event" is pretty vague, as is "use gaussian to calculate probability...".

Comment: predicting the next event(estimate the time that the event will happen), based on historical data. In case I'd like to calculate the proba, should i use Logistic regression or gaussian in this case and what's the difference.

Comment: Ok, well a Gaussian distribution is probably a bad idea here because the data can't be negative. You should really be choosing between logistic and Poisson, and the truth is that probably doesn't matter much. If you have many poitns that are greater than 2, then go with Poisson. But the way you should treat the time element is a much more difficult question and depends entirely on your hypothesis about the process. Is it seasonal? Is there an unknown drift over time? Is the change over time independent of geography?

Comment: Very good point. It's a rare event (Let's give an example crime), I don't know if Poisson would be great approach to predict the next time that the crime happen, but an event (crime) is entirely dependent with time/geography. what is the best approach to predict this way !